# How does Android interpret physical keyboard inputs?

Tags: keyboard, external-keyboard, input-methods, text-input, keyboard-shortcuts

I thought I had a grasp of how they work in a general sense, but I've been trying out several keyboards lately and have run into some inexplicable behavior.  For example, pressing the <kbd>ESC</kbd> key on one keyboard will functionally trigger the `back` function in Android, but on another keyboard it does not.  Same with mouse inputs' right clicks, seeing incongruemt behavior.  I know some keyboards have proprietary technologies that render special keys non-interoperable, but I thought the basic standard keys all trigger the same scan codes?  Why is this not the case?

Comment: Android seems to contain multiple [key layout files](https://source.android.com/devices/input/key-layout-files) may be those layout files had an impact in your case?

Comment: @Robert I select the same layout in all cases though?  I've also just noticed, the behavior seems to be application-specific, particularly Chrome.